# The entity type 'List<PersonAddress>' was not found. Ensure that the entity type has been added to the model

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-core

I'm building an application with .net core 2.0.  I have a Person object with a list of addresses. Addresses are stored in the Addresses table.  I then have a joining table that relates Person to Addresses.

```
class Person {
    public List<PersonAddress> Addresses { get; set; } 
}

class Address {
    ...address properties...
}

class PersonAddress{
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }

    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

When I save a Person object with a PersonAddress that contains an address, it works great. It inserts a new person, a new address, and a new record in the joining table. (I have configured relationships in the fluent api).

When I try to update, however, I have a problem.  After loading a person object with a list of their addresses, I can add, remove, or change the addresses, and the changes are not tracked.

I tried this in my controller to get it to process changes:

```
dbContext.Entry(person.Addresses).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

And I get this error:

`The entity type 'List<PersonAddress>' was not found. Ensure that the entity type has been added to the model.`

It is unquestionably on the model, so I don't know why this isn't working.  I trid this:

```
person.Addresses.ForEach(item => _context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified);
```

And it was ok with it, but this doesn't track adding or removing, so it's not sufficient.

Comment: Is your problem that you just want the context to show there was a dirty state?  I am curious what you are asking as you are saying there is a problem with an update but not showing an update routing but a state assignment change.

Comment: There is no entity of type List<PersonAddress>. The entry method retrieved the DbEntityEntry of that object, however lists are never part of the model, as those are usually just navigation properties with multiple entities of another type. "Track adding or removing" is just something the changetracker does, but it can't do that in disconnected scenario retroactively. Either let the changetracker track the List and do its work without reattaching it, or use the appropriate .Add, .Entry().State=Modified/Deleted methods.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro how would I go about letting the changetracker track the list?  That's what I want, but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to do that.

Comment: in order to let the list be tracked, you'll have to make the join table implicit. Otherwise you'll have to remove the PersonAddress entry, but this entity type makes little sense on its own.

Comment: Ok well I'm using EF core and you can't do implicit join tables with EF Core.  I just ended up writing the tracking code myself.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user3413723 you should have shared your solution :)

Comment: Please Share your solution

Comment: Please Share your solution +1

Comment: I am facing the same issue, could you please share the solution

Answer (score 12):

My problem was that I had a

```
var listOfItems = await DbContext.Items.ToListAsync();
DbContext.Remove(listOfItems);
```

After looking a second (10th) time over it, I realised I needed to change it to:

```
var listOfItems = await DbContext.Items.ToListAsync();
DbContext.RemoveRange(listOfItems);
```

So just needed to change from **Remove** to **RemoveRange** .

Comment: This happened to me as well. The message is not the cleanest. Because if what I (and obviously @Andrei Ivanov) did would require us to have a DbSet<List<Item>> and you probably (like I) have DbSet<Item> :) If you see it from this perspective, even the message makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the method is asynchronous and I was getting the error because I omitted the "await" keyword. see attached images, might be helpful.

[Added the await keyword](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkF52.jpg)

[Entity type not found error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zorh.png)

Comment: [Please don't post code and results as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Images should only be used as a very last resort.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code to do a diff of existing addresses and the ones the user is submitting.

```
// first, get a list of the items currently in the database
// make sure to get asNoTracking so we don't run into any weird issues
var currentList = db.Addresses.Where(item => item.PersonId == person.Id)
    .AsNoTracking().Select(item => item.AddressId);
// get a list of the ids in the newly submitted list
var newList = person.Addresses.Select(item => item.AddressId);

var newItemIds = newList.Except(currentList);
var deletedItemIds = currentList.Except(newList);
var updatedItemIds = newList.Intersect(currentList);

// now you have Ids of all that have been added, removed and updated
```